# Get third element or middle elements text of a span which are inside a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm able to get first element using $(this).children().first().text()  text & lsat element using $(this).children().last().text() of  which I've..using jquery. But, how can I get middle element using jquery?

My code

```
var data = $(this);
title = data.children().first().text();
date = data.children().last().text();
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your markup?

Comment: Might be `var third = data.children().eq(2).text();`, Note: 0 based index

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').eq(2);
```

Please use above selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq` selector.

```
 $(this).find('span:eq(2)').text()
```

Comment: I wonder how you could deduce the questioner wanted the third `<span>` element from the information in the question. Why not the second or the fourth one?

Comment: what does `Get third element ` specifies

Comment: Ah, the title, true. Apparently *or middle elements* made me forget about *third* :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: would make more sense as you have already mentioned about putting DOM to OP :)